# In the .Net DynamoDB SDK's Object Persistence model, how to find the DynamoDB attribute for a property?

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

TLDR: Does the DynamoDB SDK Context object expose its Property => Attribute mapping?

We have an application in which we primarily use the AWS DynamoDB SDK's "Object Persistence" model.

However, for some operations such as an atomic increment, we need to fall back to more low-level API operations (note: yes, I know we could also use optimistic locking and stay within the Object Persistence model, but we feel that's significant overhead for a counter). In these operations we need to refer to the DynamoDB attribute that corresponds to the property. Can we get the Property=>Attribute mapping that the DynamoDB SDK uses from anywhere?

For most properties we rely on the SDK to automatically map those - there is no explicit `[DynamoDBAttribute("foo")]` defined in most cases. Also, the attribute name can come from either DynamoDBAttribute, DynamoDBHashKey and DynamoDBRangeKey. For example, our hash keys are defined as "PK".

We could write something ourselves (check the list of attributes mentioned above, if not fallback to NameOf), but that seems redundant and might miss specific logic that the SDK already takes into account.

We did find `DynamoDbContext.getTargetTable<T>()`, which gives us the meta-data of the table, including all the attributes... but that's fully detached from the Object Persistence logic for mapping properties. Ideally there'd be a `DynamoDbContext.getTargetAttribute(PropertyInfo p)`.

Comment: Looking for the exact same thing. Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We ended up hardcoding a specific attribute name for the field being incremented. Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find one in the DynamoDb SDK, so I wrote one myself. Here is the gist of it, but in my library I am also caching the values.

```
private static string GetAttributeNameForProperty(Type type, string propertyName)
{
    var attribute = type.GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DynamoDBRenamableAttribute))
            .FirstOrDefault() as DynamoDBRenamableAttribute;
    
    var attributeName = attribute?.AttributeName ?? propertyName;
    attributeName = LowerCamelCaseCaseProperties(type) ? ToLowerCamelCase(attributeName) : attributeName;
    return attributeName;
}

private static bool LowerCamelCaseCaseProperties(Type type)
{
    var dynamoDbTableAttribute = type.GetCustomAttribute<DynamoDBTableAttribute>();
    return dynamoDbTableAttribute?.LowerCamelCaseProperties ?? false;
}

private static string ToLowerCamelCase(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || char.IsLower(value[0]))
        return value;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(value);
    stringBuilder[0] = char.ToLowerInvariant(stringBuilder[0]);
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
[DynamoDBTable("TestTable", true)]
public class Person
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    
    [DynamoDBProperty("CustomAddressName")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

// returns "customAddressName" because LowerCamelCaseProperties is true
var attributeName = GetAttributeNameForProperty(typeof(Person), nameof(Person.Address));
```